# All the standard ways (commands-packages) of changes in the font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, big-list

**Edit:**

After @samcarter's comment with the existing list on CTAN I updated my question to make it useful:

What are the possible commands-packages that will change the font globally or locally?

The purpose of the question is to have a way to recognize all these commands and maybe make a tool that will search and find such commands+ the packages that changes the font.

PS: The CTAN list that @samcarter mentioned is already half the answer...

**Old Question:**
Coming from this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411063/120578 and thought it would be nice to create a list with the packages that change the font in LaTeX so that someone will easily recognize them (as in case of the linked question) or can play around and use them to see if some of them is appropriate for his needs:

PS: Feel free to ask me to delete the question if you think it will not be useful.

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/font as starting point

Comment: @samcarter, Thanks!... I suppose I have to delete or to edit my question... Don't you thing?

Comment: The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) is also a useful resource.

Comment: @cfr the whole question started from the linked question, I am taliking about "standard ways" meaning commands like \sfdefault or \setsansfont{} etc... I don't think they are really many. I mean that usually in a template, has to be used one of thes main commands as a starter to set a main font. Then if the command will be included in another macro, if you find this first command in there you can find the next ones to.... The whole question was about finding a global solution of that linked question and gain some more benefits out of it. (Feel free to delete the post and don't even ask)

Comment: So you mean LaTeX? `\setsansfont` is not standard: it is added by `fontspec`. You might as well say `\sishape` is standard (which is added by `nfssext-cfr`) or `\scslshape` (which is, if I remember right, added by `fontaxes`). Look at `nfssext-cfr.sty` and you will see many definitions of macros which don't include one of the standard LaTeX NFSS macros. Similarly for `fontaxes.sty`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162622/what-is-the-difference-between-normal-text-and-roman-upright/162630#162630, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352194/making-slanted-small-capital-letter (one answer with `fontaxes` and one with snippets modified from `nfssext-cfr`), https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live (font sampler), etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For packages, see [What font packages are installed in TeX live?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live/249139#249139).

For coverage of NFSS, see [What font packages are installed in TeX live?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live/249139#249139).

For coverage of macros added by `fontspec`, see [fontspec](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).

For macros added by `nfssext-cfr`, see [nfssext-cfr](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nfssext-cfr/nfssext-cfr.pdf).

For macros added by `fontaxes`, see [fontaxes](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontaxes/fontaxes.pdf).

Note that both `nfssext-cfr` and `fontaxes` provide some macros which are simple extensions of NFSS, but include others which change weight, width or shape by *changing family*, where the limitations of NFSS make it impossible to have things 'work as expected' otherwise. Moreover, `nfssext-cfr`, at least, redefines some standard font macros, specifically those affecting the selection of italic and/or small-caps, in order to allow changes to accumulate 'normally'.

For example, here's the new definition of `\itshape`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\itshape}{%
  \not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
  \exfs@merge@shape{\itdefault}{\scdefault}{\sidefault}}
```

and here's `\scshape`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scshape}{%
  \not@math@alphabet\scshape\relax
  \def\tempu{u}%
  \def\tempo{ol}%
  \ifx\f@shape\tempu
        \exfs@merge@shape{\scdefault}{\udefault}{\scudefault}%
  \else
        \ifx\f@shape\tempo
                \exfs@merge@shape{\scdefault}{\oldefault}{\scoldefault}%
        \else
                \exfs@merge@shape{\scdefault}{\itdefault}{\sidefault}%
        \fi
  \fi}
```

What does `\exfs@merge@shape` do?

```
\newcommand*{\exfs@merge@shape}[3]{%
  \edef\exfs@tempa{#1}%
  \edef\exfs@tempb{#2}%
  \ifx\f@shape\exfs@tempb
    \expandafter\ifx\csname\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/#3\endcsname\relax
    \else
      \edef\exfs@tempa{#3}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \fontshape{\exfs@tempa}\selectfont}
```

This is relatively straightforward - we are not switching families here.

But suppose we look at `\tlstyle`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tlstyle}{%
        \lstyle\tstyle}
```

Well, neither `\lstyle` nor `\tstyle` is standard. What do they do?

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tstyle}{%                tabular figures
        \not@math@alphabet\tstyle\relax
        \exfs@unmerge@families{2}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lstyle}{%                lining figures (cf. command above)
        \not@math@alphabet\lstyle\relax
        \exfs@unmerge@families{j}}
```

Here's what `\exfs@unmerge@families` does:

```
\newcounter{taken}%
\newcommand*\exfs@unmerge@families[1]{%
        \edef\exfs@tempf{#1}%
        \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@get@variants\f@family\@nil}%
        \let\exfs@tempq\@empty
        \edef\exfs@tempg{}%
        \setcounter{taken}{0}%
        % check whether there are variants - if not do nothing
        \ifx\tempa\@empty
                \edef\exfs@tempq{}%
        \else
                % o/w go through the variants to find the one to delete
                \whiledo{\value{taken}<1}{%
                        % get the next variant
                        \edef\exfs@tempn{\expandafter\exfs@next\tempa\@nil}%
                        % see if the next variant is the thing we seek and, if so, eliminate it
                        \ifx\exfs@tempf\exfs@tempn
                                \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
                                \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg\tempa}%
                                \stepcounter{taken}%
                        % o/w save the next variant and move on if any variants remain
                        \else
                                \edef\exfs@tempg{\exfs@tempg\exfs@tempn}%
                                \edef\tempa{\expandafter\exfs@shift\tempa\@nil}%
                                \ifx\tempa\@empty% if there are no variants left, we're done
                                        \edef\exfs@tempq{\exfs@tempg}%
                                        \stepcounter{taken}%
                                \fi
                        \fi
                }%
        \fi
        \exfs@try@family{\expandafter\exfs@get@base\f@family\@nil \exfs@tempq}}
```

As you might guess, there is also a `\exfs@merge@families` which is needed, for example, for `\pstyle` and `\ostyle`, used by `\postyle` etc.

There is nothing to stop a 'template' using something like `\plstyle` in `\AtBeginDocument` to change the style of figures globally. (Of course, `nfssest-cfr` must be loaded to avoid an error and more must be done for it to have any effect.)

Similar comments apply to `fontaxes`, I believe. Certainly if faces the same problems in terms of the limitations of NFSS. I've focused on `nfssext-cfr` only because I happen to be rather more familiar with its eccentricities. (It is based on `nfssext.sty`, which I did not write and cannot be blamed for, but I certainly added my own share of shenanigans, for which I presumably can.)

All of this is to say, that there is no useful set of standard macros you can search for and be reasonably confident you've found what you're looking for. `fontspec`, `fontaxes` and `nfssext-cfr` are three ways of extending the standard set, but individual font packages often add macros, too.

Furthermore, a 'template' might not load a package, even if there is one. It might instead input the `.fd` file directly or set up the font families directly. Nor is this always a symptom of bad design: there are cases where this is the only way to get the desired result.

And of course, this answer only addresses fonts for text mode: fonts for maths mode are configured using an almost entirely different set of macros. The glimmer of hope here is that there are far fewer packages attempting to extend or alter these, so the situation is, in at least some sense, more manageable. Still `unicode-math` and `mathspec` are both options, here, so the situation is only really more manageable in their absence.

Comment: My favorite never used package: https://ctan.org/pkg/typeface

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner NFSS says italic is shape `it` and small-caps `sc`. So switching to small-caps or italic is generally just a matter of setting the appropriate shape. But if you have italic small-caps, you want `\textsc{\textit{abc}}` and `\textit{\textsc{abc}}` should use those. But now it is complicated, because we can't just set a new shape (e.g. `si`), we need to redefine what `\scshape` and `\itshape` do, so that they check if we're already using italics or small-caps respectively. Thus are created nightmares. ;)

Comment: @clemens Interesting indeed - I'd never heard of it. Do you mean you haven't used it or that people generally don't? That is, I'm not clear if you are saying you've found it to be great and it should be recognised more widely or that you've never used it, but it sure sounds good.

Comment: @clemens Too bad that `typeface` doesn't make use of the support provided by `cfr-lm` :-). That would be both better and more comprehensive. The method for supporting hanging figures is not very nice, in my view (and the `.sty` file comments as much, although it is more optimistic than I would be about likely fallout). Sadly, it doesn't provide access to proportional figures at all, as far as I can tell - either hanging or lining. However, no doubt this is rather nit-picking of me. ;) It is certainly an ambitious package. Does anybody use it?

Comment: @cfr I've never seen it used and I don't use it myself. I quite like the idea behind the package (which is what I meant by “favorite”). It's been a while since I took a look at it but IIRC the current release status is rather to gain feedback than general usage.